# Вывод данных из дб

Tags: php, mysqli, вывод

Есть бд - registration, с таблицей - information .В таблице имеются данные о некоторых людях. Например - фамилия,имя,год рождения и т.д. Я всё это вывел на сайт,но дело в том что,когда я пробую подключить к нему стили,в частности hover,то он не обрабатывает их,работает только на последний участок выведенных данных.[image: При hover'e[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8XO.png)

Код:

```
<div class = 'content' >     
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration"); 
/* проверяем соединение */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$link ->set_charset("utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `information`";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class = 'user'> <a class = 'user_name'>" .$user['name']."</a></br>"
    ."<a class = 'user_data'>Возраст: ".$user['data']."</a></br>"
    ."<a class = 'user_vk'>Мой Вк: ".$user ['vk']."</a></br>"
    ."</div>";
}
/* возвращаем имя текущей базы данных */
#if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
#}
/* изменяем текущую базу данных на world */
#mysqli_select_db($link, "world");
/* возвращаем имя текущей базы данных */
#if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
#    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
#    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
#    mysqli_free_result($result);
#}

mysqli_close($link);

?>



</div>
```

P.s Прошу прощения за подачу кода.

Comment: искренне сочувствую людям, которые мешают логику с представлением, а потом поддерживают эту солянку.

Comment: зы: где стили о которых вы писали?

Comment: Когда пишете текст, то после запятой нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ставить пробел ("фамилия,имя,год" -> "фамилия, имя, год")...